# Unable to setup Kinetic on docker

Tags: ros, docker, master, multiple-machines

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello all,

I'm working on having a docker container to use later on the robot.
My approach is to have a multiple machine setup where the master is in the container and Gazebo and all sorts of other GUI intensive stuff can work from outside the container.

So I started by following the [Multiple Machines tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/MultipleMachines) inside the container (just to see how far I could get). It turns out that if I start a roscore on one bash and call rosrun from another they do not hear each other.

According to [docker documentation](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/NetworkSetup),

> you can supply -P or
> --publish-all=true|false to docker run which is a blanket operation that
> identifies every port with an EXPOSE
> line in the image’s Dockerfile

`sudo docker run -P -it osrf/ros:kinetic-desktop-xenial`       Start docker container (using -P )
`roscore`        It went straight into the container so this is already inside the container, on the first bash
`docker exec -it <name>`   this is done in another terminal to open another bash for the same container
Here name is just a placeholder for the name of the container (like optimistic_aryabhata)
Inside this second bash, I set up for the tutorial

```
source /opt/ros/$ROS_DISTRO/setup.bash
apt-get update
apt-get install wget
wget http://packages.ros.org/ros.key -O - |  apt-key add -
apt-get update
apt-get install python-catkin-tools
```

And follow the tutorial instructions for [multiple machines](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/MultipleMachines)

```
export ROS_MASTER_URI=http://<name>:11311
rosrun rospy_tutorials listener.py
```

The last command gives me

```
Unable to register with master node [http://<name>:11311]: master may not be running yet. Will keep trying.
```

I was asked what was the `ROS_HOSTNAME`. I was not aware of the `ROS_IP` / `ROS_HOSTNAME` environmental variables. Neither is set. (I'm exploring this right now)

Another question was about [NetworkSetup](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/NetworkSetup). I did not follow this tutorial yet under the assumption that first I need to be able to make roscore discoverable between terminals of the same machine to go into this part of the setup.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/273281/unable-to-setup-kinetic-on-docker/) by [kotoko](https://answers.ros.org/users/27417/kotoko/) on ROS Answers with karma: 122 on 2017-10-17

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2017-10-17**:
Are you literally using the host name `<name>` or is this some place holder that you're using for your question? Also, what do you have for `ROS_HOSTNAME`?

**Comment by [PeterMilani](https://answers.ros.org/users/3621/petermilani/) on 2017-10-17**:
Does your docker container expose the master port 11311. What is your Dockerfile? If you look at the ros [networking page](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/NetworkSetup), these and a couple of environment variables are required to allow external computers connect to a ros master.

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2017-10-18**:
You should definitely set the environment variables and try running everything again. Please read this carefully http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/EnvironmentVariables

**Comment by [kotoko](https://answers.ros.org/users/27417/kotoko/) on 2017-10-18**:
@jayess I updated the answer. I was not aware of these variables, will look into it now. If you have any advice it is most welcome :D
@PeterMilani Also updated the answer to reflect the information you asked for. Thanks for the input!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Turns out I need to do  `export ROS_MASTER_URI=http://containerIP:11311/` at every bash console that I open.

---

Originally posted by [kotoko](https://answers.ros.org/users/27417/kotoko/) with karma: 122 on 2017-10-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3